# INSERT INTO SELECT vs VALUES

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, insert

Although there is no reason (apart maybe from aesthetics) to use `INSERT INTO SELECT` when inserting a *single* row in a table, is there any difference between using this and `INSERT INTO VALUES`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Using the `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` approach allows you to pick your values from another table, based on some criteria.

```
INSERT INTO dbo.TargetTable(Col1, Col2, ...., ColN)
   SELECT Col1, Col2, ..., ColN
   FROM dbo.SourceTable
   WHERE (some condition)
```

That might be a bit easier and more readable to write, rather than having to retrieve 20 values from your source table, stash them into temporary variables, just so you can then call your `INSERT INTO dbo.Destination(....) VALUES(......)` statement...

```
DECLARE @Value1 INT
DECLARE @Value2 DATETIME
....
DECLARE @ValueN INT

SELECT 
      @Value1 = Col1,
      @Value2 = Col2,
      ....
      @ValueN = ColN
FROM 
    dbo.SourceTable
WHERE
     (some condition) 

INSERT INTO dbo.TargetTable(Col1, Col2, ...., ColN)
VALUES(@Value1, @Value2, ....., @ValueN)
```

But in the end - it's just an `INSERT`  statement that inserts data - it's really just a matter of personal preference and which approach is easier / more convenient to use....

Comment: Should your "DestinationTable" be a "SourceTable" perchance?

Answer (score 9):

SELECT allows you test for existence first

```
INSERT Target (...)
SELECT keyvalue1, value2
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Target WHERE keycol = keyvalue1)
```

Or 2 sets of values

```
INSERT Target (...)
SELECT keyvalue1, value2
UNION ALL
SELECT keyvalue1a, value2a
```

Otherwise, there is no difference for a straight list of values and one row

If your values from from another table, then just INSERT..SELECT.. of course

Or mix'n'match:

```
INSERT Target (...)
SELECT col1, col2, @parameter1, @parameter2, col14
FROM Source
```

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure what differences you're looking for but I use this all the time to do validation. If I'm inserting a row into a table with FK relationships I'll use a select on the referenced table to ensure the FK is there. Example:

Instead of

```
INSERT refTable (Tab1Key,  Tab2Key, ...)
VALUES         (@Tab1Key, @Tab2Key, ...)
```

I use

```
INSERT refTable (Tab1Key,  Tab2Key, ...)
SELECT          Tab1.Key, Tab2.Key, ...
  FROM Table1 Tab1, Table2 Tab2
 WHERE Tab1.Key = @Tab1Key
   AND Tab2.Key = @Tab2Key
```

The result is the same except that No rows are inserted if the keys don't exist.

Answer (score 2):

INSERT INTO ... SELECT Vs INSERT INTO VALUES is one of the unremarkable differences that a level of performance has observed considering tables with large amounts of data: INSERT INTO ... SELECT Locks the table while the insert is being made. therefore the table cannot be used for other processes at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

I had to insert into a table some data about (14000 rows) from a text file that I copied in a query, I added the insert statement and the table was populated in about 30 seconds with 'insert select union all'. It took only 4 seconds if a changed that to 'insert values'. The downside of insert values is that I had to copy paste the insert statement every 1000 rows (because of it's limitation) but that was not so much of a problem. So when you have so many rows you can see the difference between the two...